# generate alert on button click based on input type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html that has tile view and each tile has some info with button. I want to check the value of an input hidden field and if the value is not in array defined raise an alert.

#### html

```
  <div class="box" style="width:30%%">
  <div class="boxInner">

  <form id="form_myws" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="%s">
   <div class="titleBox">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="ws_butt" id="submit" />
    </div>

  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

#### javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var state_list=["AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED","INOPERABLE",];
    var curr_state=$(this).find("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");
    console.log(curr_state.val());
    if (jQuery.inArray(curr_state.val(),state_list)<0){
            alert("submission is allowed only with AVAILABLE,IMPAIRED,INOPERABLE states.");
    }
});
```

It is not generating any alert. How to achieve that?

Comment: replace `var curr_state=$(this).find("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");` by  `var curr_state=$("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");` as `find()` method find only child elements

Comment: I already tried that but did not work. Also, I think every box has button so I need to tell js to trigger based on state value within that box.

Comment: then use `$(this).closest("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");` instead of `find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var curr_state=$(this).find("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");
```

change it to

```
var curr_state=$(this).closest('form').find("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");
```

also add

```
return false;
```

inside if statement so it won't submit form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subvert `submit` you need to do:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){

    // this:
    e.preventDefault();

    // more code

    // .. or better
    return false;

});
```

You can contain these responses in if --> then constructs but you need to do one or the other to prevent a form from submitting. If you're not using a form, don't use `submit`!

You can also access the hidden input value like this:

```
$('#form_myws > input[name="state"]').val();
```

Working snippet:

```js
var val = $('#form_myws > input[name="state"]').val();

$('body').append(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="form_myws">
  <input type="hidden" name="state" value="%s">
  <div class="titleBox">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="ws_butt" id="submit" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case:

```
 var curr_state=$(this).find("input[type='hidden'][name='state']");
```

`$(this)` get the button element you selected , you can't find any childen nodes via `find()` So you should select the hidden input correctly like:

```
 var curr_state=$($(this).parent()[0]).prev()[0];
```

or like this:

```
    var curr_state=$($(this).parent()[0]).siblings('[name="state"]')[0];
```

Comment: it is not generating any alert neither not getting any console prints on button click. I think I need to refer to $(this) button since every box has button.

Comment: when you press the submit button, it posts the form and refresh the page, so you can't see it. try remove the method attribute from form element

Comment: changed the js to this but still not working                     <script type="text/javascript">
   $(this).closest("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
        var state_list=["AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED","INOPERABLE",];
        var curr_state=$($(this).parent()[0]).siblings('[name="state"]')[0].value;
        console.log("in javascript");
        console.log(curr_state);
        if (jQuery.inArray(curr_state,state_list)<0){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("submission is allowed only with AVAILABLE,IMPAIRED,INOPERABLE states.");
        }
    });
  </script>

Comment: I have managed it. <script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var state_list=["AVAILABLE","IMPAIRED","INOPERABLE",];
  var curr_state=$($(this).parent()[0]).prev()[0].value;
     console.log(curr_state);
    if (jQuery.inArray(curr_state,state_list)<0){
            alert("submission is allowed only with AVAILABLE,IMPAIRED,INOPERABLE states.");
    }
});
</script>

Comment: before you test , you should remove the `<form>`  or set a wrong value on `<input type='hidden' value="not in array'>` so you can see the feedback.

Comment: but even button click is not getting triggered. Since every box has button and there are multiple box on the screen so do I need to refer to the current clicked box button? Can someone provide a fiddle for it?

Comment: `$this` can refer to the button you pressed even if there are many boxes , you shold add class to every button so you can use `$('.btn_submit')` to bind click event to all buttons . only to change  `$('#submit').click(function()` to `$('.submit').click(function()`